# Nancy - two modules listening on different ports

Tags: c#, .net, nancy

The idea is that I have two `NancyModule` classes that will be handling traffic on two different ports. For instance:

- `FirstModule` listening on `localhost:8081`
- `SecondModule` listening on `localhost:8082`

I'm currently using `Nancy.Hosting.Self` to create Nancy instances on both `localhost:8081` and `localhost:8082`:

```
internal static void Main(string[] args) {
    var uris = new Uri[] {
        new Uri("localhost:8081"),
        new Uri("localhost:8082"),
    };

    var host = new NancyHost(uris);
    host.Start();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

How do I make class `FirstModule : NancyModule` listen only on port `8081` and `SecondModule : NancyModule` listen only on port `8082`?

```
public class FirstModule : NancyModule {
    public FirstModule(){
        Get["/"] = _ => "Hello from FirstModule!"
    }
}

public class SecondModule : NancyModule {
    public FirstModule(){
        Get["/"] = _ => "Hello from SecondModule!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not have two separate sites and use two separate processes to sself host them listening on separate ports?

Comment: What would the real use for this be though?

Comment: I'm building a configurable "stub" server. One will be hosting canned responses to configured URLs. The other will serve as a restful endpoint for modifying the currently loaded responses being served on the first. We've already implemented this tool for both Java and Node.js

Answer (score 9):

you could split it up into separate projects for each server with a custom bootstrapper to separate the NancyModule registration.

This example is a three part solution with two class libraries for each server and one console application to launch them.

First Server Project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Nancy;
using Nancy.Bootstrapper;
using Nancy.Hosting.Self;

namespace Server1
{
    public class Server : NancyModule
    {
        private static NancyHost _server;

        public static void Start()
        {
            _server = new NancyHost(new Bootstrapper(), new Uri("http://localhost:8686"));
            _server.Start();
        }

        public Server()
        {
            Get["/"] = _ => "this is server 1";
        }
    }

    public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Register only NancyModules found in this assembly
        /// </summary>
        protected override IEnumerable<ModuleRegistration> Modules
        {
            get
            {
                return GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.BaseType == typeof(NancyModule)).Select(type => new ModuleRegistration(type, this.GetModuleKeyGenerator().GetKeyForModuleType(type)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second server project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Nancy;
using Nancy.Bootstrapper;
using Nancy.Hosting.Self;

namespace Server2
{
    public class Server : NancyModule
    {
        private static NancyHost _server;

        public static void Start()
        {
            _server = new NancyHost(new Bootstrapper(), new Uri("http://localhost:9696"));
            _server.Start();
        }

        public Server()
        {
            Get["/"] = _ => "this is server 2";
        }
    }

    public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Register only NancyModules found in this assembly
        /// </summary>
        protected override IEnumerable<ModuleRegistration> Modules
        {
            get
            {
                return GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.BaseType == typeof(NancyModule)).Select(type => new ModuleRegistration(type, this.GetModuleKeyGenerator().GetKeyForModuleType(type)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Launch them both from a separate Console application or whatever

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Server1.Server.Start();
            Server2.Server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("servers started...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Didn't you get any exception?

if you have multiple 'DefaultNancyBootstrapper' either in same Assembly or in the separate assembly files (dll, exe) in the same directory, then you will get exception saying "Located multiple bootstrappers:" 

I'm still having this problem

Comment: @Locke If you get `Located multiple bootstrappers:` then just specify a more concrete Bootstrapper in `_server = new NancyHost(new Bootstrapper(), new Uri("http://localhost:9696"));`

E.g. `_server = new NancyHost(new MyLocalBootstrapper(), new Uri("http://localhost:9696"));`

Comment: @Sammi I just call 'WebApp.Start()' and 'UseNancy()'.
I think I need to change the way I start the server, but how?

Comment: I did it like this guy here: http://www.strathweb.com/2013/05/the-future-is-now-owin-and-multi-hosting-asp-net-web-applications/

`var startOptions = new StartOptions ();
startOptions.Urls.Add ("http://+:9696");
using (WebApp.Start(startOptions, builder => {
    var nancyOptions = new NancyOptions();
    nancyOptions.Bootstrapper = new MyLocalBootstrapper();
    builder.UseNancy(nancyOptions);
}))
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}`

Comment: Doesn't work, give this error:
Error CS1061 'Bootstrapper' does not contain a definition for 'GetModuleKeyGenerator' and no extension method 'GetModuleKeyGenerator' accepting a first argument of type 'Bootstrapper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Server

Comment: Somebody does know how to fix it?