# Nancy listening on two diferents address

Tags: c#, nancy

I want to make program with two kind of API. One API should listening on IP address (eg 192.168.1.20). This API must have 2 methods. Other API should listening on localhost and have one method. I try to use Nancy. I read this topic [Nancy - two modules listening on different ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436914/nancy-two-modules-listening-on-different-ports) but I have some error. Could you help me with compile this?

```
Error   CS1061  'Bootstrapper' does not contain a definition for 'GetModuleKeyGenerator' and no extension method 'GetModuleKeyGenerator' accepting a first argument of type 'Bootstrapper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This error appeared in this class in return line

```
 public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Register only NancyModules found in this assembly
    /// </summary>
    protected override IEnumerable<ModuleRegistration> Modules
    {
        get
        {
            return GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.BaseType == typeof(NancyModule)).Select(type => new ModuleRegistration(type, this.GetModuleKeyGenerator().GetKeyForModuleType(type)));
        }
    }
}
```

And code of all file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Nancy;
using Nancy.Bootstrapper;
using Nancy.Hosting.Self;

namespace Server1
{
    public class Server : NancyModule
    {
        private static NancyHost _server;

        public static void Start()
        {
            _server = new NancyHost(new Bootstrapper(), new Uri("http://localhost:8686"));
            _server.Start();
        }

        public Server()
        {
            Get["/"] = _ => "this is server 1";
        }
    }

    public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Register only NancyModules found in this assembly
        /// </summary>
        protected override IEnumerable<ModuleRegistration> Modules
        {
            get
            {
                return GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.BaseType == typeof(NancyModule)).Select(type => new ModuleRegistration(type, this.GetModuleKeyGenerator().GetKeyForModuleType(type)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank for yours time!